# Having issue with jest test for Lightning Quick action and CloseActionScreenEvent

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

We have a lightning web component which uses lightning quick action tag and this line in js file:

```
import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from "lightning/actions";
```

And when I run jest test I have got the error. So I have gone through the existing question and have updated my package.json file into:

```
"@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest": "^1.0.0",
```

And I have also updated the sfdx-project version to 53. The Cannot find module 'lightning/quickActionPanel' error is gone. But I am still seeing the below error:

> Cannot find module 'lightning/actions'

In CloseActionScreenEvent js file line. How should we walkaround this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [sfdx-lwc-jest](https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/tree/master/src/lightning-stubs) repository, you can see what `lightning-stubs` they've created.

[QuickActionPanel](https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/blob/master/src/lightning-stubs/quickActionPanel/quickActionPanel.js) has an appropriate stub which is why updating to the a later version (that added this stub) solved your initial issue, but you'll notice there is none for `lightning/actions`. As a result, you have to create one yourself.

There's actually an example of creating your own [jest-mocks](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/actions.js) in the [lwc-recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes) that allows them to create a jest test for the [editRecordScreen](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/editRecordScreenAction/__tests__) component.

```js
/**
 * Close Screen Action Event base class
 */
export const CloseScreenEventName = 'lightning__actionsclosescreen';

export class CloseActionScreenEvent extends CustomEvent {
    constructor() {
        super(CloseScreenEventName, { bubbles: false, composed: false });
    }
}
```

Then, in your jest test

```js
import { CloseScreenEventName } from 'lightning/actions';
```