# Cannot find module 'lightning/actions' import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from "lightning/actions";

Tags: lightning-web-components, unit-test, lwc-jest

Is there a valid solution for this issue in latest versions of @salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest?  I implemented the below solution and still get the error:

"@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest": "1.1.0"
sfdx-cli: sfdx-cli/7.179.0 darwin-x64 node-v18.12.1

in process of updating to even newer lwc-jest but looking at the repo still no stubs for CloseActionScreenEvent

Ive tried the solution listed here [Having issue with jest test for Lightning Quick action and CloseActionScreenEvent](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/360353/having-issue-with-jest-test-for-lightning-quick-action-and-closeactionscreeneven)

with no luck still get same error cannot find module 'lightning/actions'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not in `@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest`, it's found in [`@trailheadapps/lwc-recipes`](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes).

Setting this up is pretty trivial, though not necessarily very obvious what you're supposed to do.

Starting from the linked repository above, you first will want to install `@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest` if you haven't yet:

```
npm i --save-dev @salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest
```

This installs the `config.js` referenced in the next step.

You should have a file called `jest.config.js` in your project root, written as follows (note: this is in `@trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/jest.config.js`):

```
const { jestConfig } = require('@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/config');
const setupFilesAfterEnv = jestConfig.setupFilesAfterEnv || [];
setupFilesAfterEnv.push('<rootDir>/jest-sa11y-setup.js');
module.exports = {
    ...jestConfig,
    moduleNameMapper: {
        /* CSS library import fix in test context. See:
        https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/issues/288) */
        '^c/cssLibrary$':
            '<rootDir>/force-app/main/default/lwc/cssLibrary/cssLibrary.css',
        // Jest mocks
        '^@salesforce/apex$': '<rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/apex',
        '^@salesforce/schema$': '<rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/schema',
        '^lightning/navigation$':
            '<rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/navigation',
        '^lightning/platformShowToastEvent$':
            '<rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/platformShowToastEvent',
        '^lightning/uiRecordApi$':
            '<rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/uiRecordApi',
        '^lightning/messageService$':
            '<rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/messageService',
        '^lightning/actions$':
            '<rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/actions',
        '^lightning/alert$':
            '<rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/alert',
        '^lightning/confirm$':
            '<rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/confirm',
        '^lightning/prompt$':
            '<rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/prompt',
        '^lightning/modal*':
            '<rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/modal'
    },
    setupFiles: ['jest-canvas-mock'],
    setupFilesAfterEnv,
    testTimeout: 10000
};
```

You can remove any module names you don't need. The important part here is in `moduleNameMapper` for `'^lightning/actions$`. You'll notice that that this maps to a file:

```
<rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/actions
```

So, you should set up this folder structure in your project. Inside `force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning`, create a file called `actions.js`, and place the contents of [this file](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/actions.js) there.

```
/**
 * Close Screen Action Event base class
 */
export const CloseScreenEventName = 'lightning__actionsclosescreen';

export class CloseActionScreenEvent extends CustomEvent {
    constructor() {
        super(CloseScreenEventName, { bubbles: false, composed: false });
    }
}
```

This is found in [`@trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/actions.js`](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/actions.js).

---

So, in summary, install `@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest`, configure a `jest.config.js`, and copy the relevant modules from `@trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/force-app/test/jest-mocks`.

Comment: yup that is the part i was missing lol the module name mapper.  i was gunna close this out this morning cause i figured out finally but rather keep it here for future users and for credit on your answer.  Thanks